# How to display consol.log() result in browser terminal or other

Tags: angular, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging

I use Jest framework for unit testing,when i use consol.log() for debugging purpose like below:

```
  it('should create', () => {
    console.log(component.selectComponentRef);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

it displays in visual-studio terminal,i would like to display console.log() results in browser terminal or other,do you know how to achive that?

Comment: with Jasmine it appears in both, i think you need to click the debug button first from the browser window

Answer (score 0):

Since Jest runs independently of a browser (which many consider a strength), you won’t be able to see console.log output in the browser using Jest.